# Avoiding namespace collisions

Tags: javascript

I'm building a small javascript file that is going to be used on third party websites, and it has some dependencies like `json2.js` and `underscore.js`. Some of the commonly used libraries provide `noConflict` methods to avoid namespace collisions, but `json2.js` does not have a way of doing that. Is there a way to use these dependencies without making any changes on global variables like `JSON` (also without modifying the dependency files)?

I'm aware json2.js only modifies the global scope in older browsers, but it is just an example.

Comment: So, you want to load json2.js, but not have it modify `window.JSON`?  What are you trying to do?  I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: You could look into [require js](http://requirejs.org) specifically [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is something like this:

```
(function() {
  //JSON2.js code here
  myFunction = function() {
     JSON.stringify(..); //reference to JSON2 here
  }
})();
```